# Two questions on using Apache ant

Tags: java, ant

I am learning to build automatic Java compiling script using Ant. With respect to the following code segment, what does the default="dist" stand for?  For the basedir=".", does "." mean the working directory, which has build.xml stored?

```
<project name="Myproject" default="dist" basedir=".">
```

With respect to the following segment, what does  location="src"/ stand for?

```
<property name = "src" location="src"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The `default` attribute](http://ant.apache.org/manual/using.html#projects) indicates the target which will be executed if you are calling `ant` without any target argument. Thus with this setting, `ant` will be synonymous to `ant dist`.

The `basedir` attribute is interpreted relatively to the parent directory of `build.xml`, yes. (This directory is usually the same as the current working directory, but does not have to be.)

The `location` attribute of the [property task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/property.html) converts a path relative to the projects `basedir` to an absolute path. Thus, in your case you will get the absolute path of `src` in the buildfile's directory. (It will also do conversion of `/` and `\` to your platform's conventions.)

Answer (score 2):

These are things easily [read in the Ant Manual](http://ant.apache.org/manual/)

```
<project name="Myproject" default="dist" basedir=".">
```

This defines the [default target](http://ant.apache.org/manual/using.html#projects) to be be run if none is specified

```
<property name = "src" location="src"/>
```

See the [documentation](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/property.html) for the `<property>` task.

Answer (score 0):

1. The goal 'dist' will run by default if you don't ask ant to run another.
2. A directory named 'src' in the same directory as the basedir, which is to say, wherever you are sitting when you run ant.